# How can I change the "ord" function's signature in Haskell?

Tags: function, haskell, recursion

Rookie learning recursive functions in Haskell, was wondering how can I create recursive functions toUpper and toLower, which receive a list of Chars and return the same list of Chars but in upper and lower case? I tried solving it using the chr and ord functions but ord's signature is Char -> Int and not [Char] -> [Int] so it doesn't match with toUpper and toLower's. Any ideas?

Comment: based on your description I would suggest `map toUpper` or `map toLower` - but I'm unsure if I get your question right

Comment: *How* did you try and use these? They sound like they are just what you need, if used properly.

Comment: `map toUpper "hello world"` gives you `"HELLO WORLD"` - is this what you are talking about?

Answer (score 3):

This is precisely what the `map` function does: it takes a function of type `a -> b` (for any types `a` and `b`) and returns a new function `[a] -> [b]`.

```
> :t ord
ord :: Char -> Int
> :t map ord
map ord :: [Char] -> [Int]
```

This lets you convert an entire string to its Unicode code points:

```
> map ord "foo"
[102,111,111]
```

or back

```
> map chr [102,111,111]
"foo"
```

To implement your approach, you then just need to define an appropriate functions `toLower` and `toUpper` to use with

```
> map chr (map toLower (map ord "MyStRiNg"))
mystring
> map chr (map toUpper (map ord "MyStRiNg"))
MYSTRING
```

(Note that the module `Data.Char` already supplies `toLower, toUpper :: Char -> Char`; you can use them to check your own implementations.)

Answer (score -3):

Never mind, got it now. In case anyone needs it:

```
toUpper::[Char] -> [Char]
toUpper [] = []
toUpper (x:xs) = chr(ord(x)-32):toUpper(xs)

toLower::[Char] -> [Char]
toLower [] = []
toLower (x:xs) = chr(ord(x)+32):toLower(xs)
```

Comment: What about `toUpper "FOO"` or `toLower "foo"`? That problem aside, you are just re-implementing the logic `map` already provides. `map f [] = []` and `map f (x:xs) = (f x):(map f xs)`.

Comment: That's a terrible way of doing it.